# Mod rewrite - rewrite everything but

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ allcities.php?state=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Howver how can I change it so it doesn't rewrite a new directory I have created, such as "admin". As currently that is being rewritten as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond` for that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ allcities.php?state=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note the exclamation mark before the regex on the `RewriteCond`. It makes the regex revert its meaning. So in this case, the condition is true, if the request URI does not start with `/admin`.

Please see the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. However what happens if there is a file that starts with admin? Can you change it to /admin/ without any problems?

Comment: Yes, you can use whatever regexes you require, e.g. `^/admin/?$` which will match the path with an optional trailing slash.

Comment: @HolgerJust I think you mean `^/admin(/|$)` - the rule as you wrote it will ONLY not-match on /admin or /admin/ exactly.

Comment: @fluffy what will your version do?

Comment: That's what I intended. But yeah, that's not necessarily what Brett actually wanted :) But as I'm generally rather bad a guessing...

Comment: Mine will match for /admin exactly or anything starting with /admin/ - i.e. it will treat /admin as a directory.  Also note that if you just put your .htaccess inside the /admin directory itself (assuming it is an actual directory on your file system) that will override the .htaccess rules for /.

Comment: @fluffy: Another variant of that schema (which I also use for proxy rules) is `^/admin(/.*)?`

Comment: @HolgerJust You still need a $ at the end of that in order to prevent it from matching, say, /administrator or the like.

Comment: Sorry, one more question.... if there are rules below this rule, will the `RewriteCond` also affect them? As I don't want it to.

Comment: nvm... I read that page you linked me to and from what I could tell the `RewriteCond` only applies to the rule directly under it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are processed in the order that they are received. You will need to have a handler that will route to the existing directory before that rule is processed.  For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ allcities.php?state=$1 [QSA,L]
```